# C++ Overloading assignment operator: "cannot convert `B*` to `A*`" error

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

```
class B;

class A{

    B *b;
    public:
    void operator= (B *b){
        this->b = b;
    }
}; 

B *b = new B()
A *a = new A();
a = b;
```

I get a "cannot convert `B*` to `A*`" error.
Is there a way around this?

Now, if there is a way, and if I use something like:

```
a = NULL;
```

Which operator "=" would be used?

Comment: Your overload assigns to `A`, not `A*`.

Comment: You are assigning a pointer to a `B` to a pointer to an `A`, which is not the same as assigning a `B` to an `A`.

Comment: Thank you to all. Rookie mistake!

Comment: @nahpr Please consider selecting one of the answers below as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `operator=` provides assignment from a `B*` to an `A`.  Your code does not provide a conversion from a `B*` to a `A*` (as the error message shows).  As such, `a=NULL` will not use the assignment operator you provided, since `a` is a pointer, not an `A`.  Your code allows assignment from a `B*` to an `A`, like `A a= new B();`.

If you meant to be using actual objects instead of pointers, remove all the `*` from your code:

```
class B{};    
class A{    
    B b;
    public:
    void operator= (const B& b){ //pass non-primitives by const reference
        this->b = b;
    }
}; 

B b;
A a;
a = b;
```

If you wanted to be using pointers, the only "useful" way to assign a `B*` to an `A*` is if a `B` object derives from `A`.  That appears to not be what you're doing, so assigning a `B*` to an `A*` would make no sense in your code.

Comment: To help clarify, `void operator=(B *b)` would be **only** used in the following `B b; A a = &b;`

Answer (score 8):

You have assigned the pointer instead of the object. Simply replace the last instruction with:
`*a = b;`

To answer the second question: [NULL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) can be defined in more than one way in the compiler (as of the latest standard, either as the integral `0` or the literal `nullptr`). Pointers can also be cast to pointer of other types, but passing a `void*` to an overloaded function that takes an `int*` or a `long*` may make the compiler unable to resolve the function being called.

If however, you want to avoid NULL, simply make `operator(B& b)` instead. References are sure to be pointing at an object.

Comment: In C++ NULL is defined as 0.  This is the only definition that is legal.

Comment: I have definitely observed NULL being defined as `((void*)0)` in MSVC2008.

Comment: In C++ NULL has to be a null pointer constant (usually an integer constant expression with value 0). Unlike in C `((void*)0)` is not valid, it cannot be converted, say, to `int*` without a cast.

Answer (score 2):

Change your statement that assigns to a to:

```
*a = b;
```